# ADE classification of singular surfaces in catastrophe theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, catastrophe-theory

I have seen a lot the Arnold's classification of singular surfaces by the simple Lie groups. I have even asked the author of a book that used this classification about its origin and his answer was that when he wrote it someone explained him the connection, but he had long forgotten it.

Is there anywhere a simple explanation of the connection? I would like to understand the main idea without going into a lot of details.

Comment: http://touch-geometry.karazin.ua/list